# $\|(g\widehat{(f|f|^{2})})^{\vee}\|_{L^{2}} \leq C \|f\|_{L^{2}}^{r} \|(g\hat{f})^{\vee}\|_{L^{2}}$ for some $r\geq 1$?

Tags: analysis, inequality, proof-verification, fourier-analysis

Let $g\in C_{c}^{\infty} (\mathbb R)$, and $f, |f|^{2}f\in L^{2}(\mathbb R)\cap C_{0}(\mathbb R)$ (where $C_{c}(\mathbb R)$ is the class of smooth functions with compact support and $C_{0}(\mathbb R)$ is the class of continuous functions vanishing at infinity).

> **My Question** : Can we expect: $\|(g\widehat{(f|f|^{2})})^{\vee}\|_{L^{2}} \leq C \|f\|_{L^{2}}^{r} \|(g\hat{f})^{\vee}\|_{L^{2}}$ for some $r\geq 1$? (where $C$ is some constant)

[where $\widehat{f|f|^{2}}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f|f|^{2}$ and $(g\widehat{(f|f|^{2})})^{\vee}$ denotes the inverse Fourier transform of $g\widehat{(f|f|^{2}})$; and $|f|^{2}= f \bar{f}$]

Thanks,

**EDIT**: (Where is the mistake in the below argument)

Suppose $g$ has a compact support, say $K\subset \mathbb R.$ And additionally I am assuming that $g\leq 1.$
Now, 
\begin{eqnarray}
\|(g\widehat{|f|^{2}f})^{\vee}\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb R)} & = & \|g\widehat{(|f|^{2}f)}\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb R)} \nonumber \\
                                         & = & \|g\widehat{|f|} \ast g\widehat{|f|}\ast g\hat{f}\|_{L^{2}} \nonumber \\
                                         & \leq & \|g\widehat{|f|}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R) }^{2} \|g\hat{f}\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb R)}\nonumber\\
                                         & = & \|g\widehat{|f|}\|_{L^{1}(K)} \|g\hat{f}\|_{L^{2}}\nonumber\\
                                         & \leq & \|g\widehat{|f|}\|_{L^{2}(K)}^{2} \|g\hat{f}\|_{L^{2}}\nonumber\\
                                         & \leq & \|\widehat{|f|}\|^{2}_{L^{2}(K)}\|g\hat{f}\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb R)}\nonumber\\
                                         & \leq & \|\widehat{|f|}\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\mathbb R)} \|g\hat{f}\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb R)}\nonumber\\
                                         & = &  \|f\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\mathbb R)} \|(g\hat{f})^{\vee}\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb R)};
\end{eqnarray}
[In the first equality I have used Planchrel's theorem; fourth equality is due to $g$ has a compact support; fifth inequality is due the inclusion $L^{2}(K)\subset L^{1}(K)$; sixth inequality is due to $g\leq 1$; seventh inequality is due to 
$A\subset B \implies \int_{A} |h| dm \leq \int_{B} |h| dm$ ($dm$ Lebsgue measure)]

Comment: Why do you have equality $$\| g(\widehat{|f|² f}\| = \|g \widehat{|f|} \star g \widehat{|f|} \star g \hat{f}\|$$ I see no possible reason for this equality to hold.

Comment: @WW; thanks  a lot; now I realized my mistake:($a(f\ast g)= af\ast g, a\in \mathbb C$ is true; but $a(f\ast g)= af\ast ag, a\in \mathbb C$ may not be TRUE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written: **no**.

The scaling is not right.

Let $f_\lambda(x) = f(\lambda x)$, we have $\widehat{f_\lambda}(\xi) = \frac{1}{\lambda} \hat{f}(x / \lambda)$ and similarly $g_{\lambda}$.

Consider your inequality with $f_\lambda$ and $g_{1/\lambda}$

Using Plancherel we want to control
$$ \| g_{1/\lambda} (\widehat{f_\lambda |f_\lambda|^2}) \|_{L^2}^2
= \int \left|g(x/\lambda) \frac{1}{\lambda} \widehat{f|f|^2}(x/\lambda)\right|^2 \mathrm{d}x \\ = \frac1{\lambda} \int | g(x/\lambda) \widehat{f|f|^2}(x/\lambda) | \mathrm{d}x / \lambda = \frac{1}{\lambda} \| g (\widehat{f|f|^2})\|_{L^2}^2 $$

The right hand side, however, scales like 
$$ \|f_\lambda\|_{L^2}^2 = \frac{1}{\lambda} \int |f(\lambda x)|^2 \lambda \mathrm{d}x = \frac1\lambda \|f\|_{L^2}^2 $$
and
$$ \| g_{1/\lambda} \widehat{f_\lambda} \|_{L^2}^2 = \int | g(x/\lambda) \frac{1}{\lambda} \hat{f}(x/\lambda) |^2 \mathrm{d}x 
= \frac{1}{\lambda} \|g \widehat{f}\|_{L^2}^2 $$

So if the proposed inequality were to hold, you would have
$$ \frac{1}{\lambda} \leq C \frac{1}{\lambda^r} \frac{1}{\lambda} $$ 
for $r \geq 1$ and for all $\lambda$, which is absurd.

---

In a more general note: for inequalities between $L^p$ spaces, you cannot really do better than what Holder inequality gives you. The bound of an $L^2$ quantity on the left hand side by products of $L^2$ quantities on the right hand side, with no weights or derivative losses, should immediately set off a red flag. Without all the Fourier transform involved you would have something like 
$$ \|g f^3\|_{L^2} \leq \begin{cases}
\|g f\|_{L^\infty} \|f\|_{L^4}^2 \\
\|g f\|_{L^2} \|f\|_{L^\infty}^2 \\
\|g f\|_{L^4} \|f\|_{L^8}^2 \end{cases} $$
and for intuition purposes you can imagine the Fourier transform as roughly interchanging $L^p$ with $L^{q}$ where $p^{-1} + q^{-1} = 1$, and you can see immediately, in a very rough sense, that the desired inequalities do not hold by scaling.

Comment: @W.W; thanks;   If I additionally assume $g\leq1,$ then I am getting the positive answer(Please see the edited question); However I don't see the mistake in my solution, but I am not confident; would you please tell me where I am doing mistake; thanks a lot.

Comment: Your second equality makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

My previous answer addressed the issue of scaling. This answer addresses the issue of support. Basically:

*There exists functions $g, f$ such that $g(\widehat{f|f|^2}) \not\equiv 0$ while $g \hat{f} \equiv 0$.*

Let $\hat{f}$ be a non-negative real valued $C^\infty_c$ function, so that automatically $f, f|f|^2\in L^2 \cap C_0$. We have that
$$ \widehat{f |f|^2} = \hat{f} \star (\hat{f} \star \hat{\bar{f}}) = \hat{f} \star (\hat{f} \star (\bar{\hat{f}} \circ \iota)) $$
where $h \circ \iota(x) = h(-x)$. 
As $\hat{f}$ is real and non-negative, we see that the support of $\widehat{f|f|^2}$ is strictly larger than the support of $\hat{f}$. Therefore there exists $g\in C^\infty_c$ such that 
$$ \operatorname{supp} g \subset (\operatorname{supp} \widehat{f|f|^2}) \setminus (\operatorname{supp} \hat{f}) $$

This argument here shows that

*Even if you change the $L^p$ norms used in the inequality so that the scaling is no longer an issue, the desired inequality cannot possibly hold.*